# How to display specific ids of posts using wp_query?

Tags: wp-query

I have 7 services in a page. All 7 services have featured images. I want to show all the 7 images and content in a slideshow.

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post__in'      => $myarray
);

// The Query<br>
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How can I show the featured image in the slide show. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

this is a fairly broad question since there are multiple solutions depending on your exact needs. My method might involve:

- Setup normal 'Loop'
- in each iteration grab the featured image using: wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( post->ID ), 'large' );
- build an unordered list of images
- Use a plugin that works with UL listitems to generated a slideshow with the desired features

That's pretty much it. Can't test this but might end up looking like:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">'; 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
         $the_query->the_post();
         echo '<li><img src="' . wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( post->ID ), 'large' ) . '" /></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></div>';
}
```

And then use maybe

[Flexslider2](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a WP query to grab posts and then put them in a Slider like Flex Slider to display them in a slider.Here is the query :-

```
<?php  
        $args = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'carousel',
            'carousel-category' => 'your-category',
            'posts_per_page' => 7
        );
        $recentPosts = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

Now grab the featured image using the following code (in loop):-

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
```

You will need to them inside Div elements to create a carousel.Here is a tutorial that you can use for better understanding :-
http://www.wordpressauthors.com/wordpress-development/display-a-carousel-of-most-recent-posts/

Hope that helps. :)